# Caching Expires Header CSS and JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, caching

I have just been trying to speed up my website.

One of the issues appearing when I do a speed test in Google is 'Leverage browser caching'. I have looked this up and added some code to my htaccess. Please see below:

```html
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

This has worked on some of my files but not all of them and I am still getting a message that loads of my js and css files are not set to expire. Could somebody help? What am I doing wrong for them to not expire? Here is my error message from Google even with the previous code in the htaccess.

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/css/grid.css (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/addons.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/addons/jquery.cookiebar.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/addons/jquery.flexslider.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/base/html5shiv.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/base/modernizr.custom.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/js/nav.js (expiration not specified)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mailer/css/form-style.css (expiration not specified)
http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js (20 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/fonts/Effra_Std_Bd.woff (2 days)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/fonts/Effra_Std_Lt.woff (2 days)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/fonts/Effra_Std_Md.woff (2 days)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/fonts/Effra_Std_Rg.woff (2 days)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mailer/js/jquery.validate.js (2 days)
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/mailer/js/validate.js (2 days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your above code there are a few missing:

```
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 year"
```

That Facebook .js file is not something you will be able to fix like the others as it's an external file... you can use a `cron` to fix that issue, which is basically storing the file and loading it locally. You will find you have the same issue with things like Google Analytics, Lead Forensics etc etc.

If you wish to attempt at using a `cron`, then take a look at this guide: http://diywpblog.com/leverage-browser-cache-optimize-google-analytics/

Although I feel it is pretty pointless, especially when it comes to Google Analytics... they're not going to punish you for their own software!